# Android ACTION_SEND Hyperlink not working in GMail

Tags: android, email, android-intent, hyperlink

This is my code for sending an HTML email in Android, with a clickable link.

```
private void sendEmail()
{

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String subject = "Prueba";
String emailtext = "<a href=http://www.google.es>PruebaEmail</a>";
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailtext.toString()));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail"));
}
```

Months ago, it was working and sends a clickable hyperlink, but for now, when I receive the mail in my GMail account, there is no hyperlink, just plain text.

I have tried all of this in the type:

```
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

and

```
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

and

```
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
```

and this for the text:

```
String emailtext = "<a href=http://www.google.es>PruebaEmail</a>";
```

and

```
String emailtext = "<a href='http://www.google.es'>PruebaEmail</a>";
```

and

```
String emailtext = "<a href="http://www.google.es">PruebaEmail</a>";
```

but none of that are working.

This issue is just for GMail, because if I send the mail to Evernote or another app, I got a clickable link.

This is my API configuration:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

and compiling with Android 3.2

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the code on my device, and its working. can you tell which device you running this/ is gmail version updated?

Comment: I have tried on my Nexus S (4.1.2) and my Nexus 10 (4.2.1), and do not working in any of them. Getting plain text on my email even having 
.setType("text/html");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK finally found the solution for the things to work.
The link in the href and outside has to be exactly same.
Deleted my comments they are now irrelevant.

The problem is with gmail client 4.2.2 i have the latest one it seems :)
The gmail client 4.1.2 worked just fine for the href tag what you had written.

And its really stupid of the gmail client to work like this.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Yes, it is such a stupid thing to work like this.

Comment: @jayshill Dave can you please share example for same