# How to pass hyperlink to Gmail in Intent ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, hyperlink, gmail

May be this question is already asked or duplicate of another question, but I didn't get any solution for my search.
Here are the links which I followed for my question:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004097/email-issue-send-hyperlink-in-email-body-android) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560717/android-action-send-hyperlink-not-working-in-gmail)

Actually, my question is related to sharing HTML text in android default intent with an ACTION_SEND. When I am trying to create a hyperlink to URL with different value then it is showing a simple text of value. That is not clickable as a link.

Here is how I am doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
String link = "https://www.android.com/";
String linkValue = "Click Me";
String body1 = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link+ "</a>";//I don't want this
String body2 = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + linkValue + "</a>";//This is not working
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body2));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share With"));
```

**For body2:**
When I share the text using Gmail then in email hyperlinked text will come as a normal text. Simply "Click Me". I checked it on desktop browser also. But there also it is same. I checked this text in Inspect Element(You can get Inspect Element of a browser page like: Right click on browser page>> In popup window click at the bottom Inspect OR refer [Inspect Element](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)) format and found there was no  tag for hyperlink text.

**For body1:**
It's working and I got the URL as a hyperlink in the email, but I got the URL as a hyperlink I don't want to show the same URL in email rather than there should be some hint value as body2 format. This format can be achieved by direct URL sharing in the body no need of  tag.

[image]

So finally my search is, Is there any way in Android for sharing hyperlink text with different hint value rather than as of link(URL).

Comment: hi please describe more your question I check both link working properly code... !

Comment: Facing same problem .Probably its a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a string resource instead of a Java string, it's generally and good practice and that way you won't have to escape the " either. And with the HTML data you'll have to wrap it in CDATA.

XML:

```
<string name="readyandroid"><![CDATA[<a href="https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/">readyandroid</a>]]></string>
```

in Java, replace body2 with:

```
String body2 = getString(R.string.readyandroid);
```

Then try passing it to the intent and sending it in an email, it should be a proper hyperlink as you would like it to be.

Comment: I tried your way previously before your answer. It didn't work for me because I was using dynamic string to share not this static. But surprisingly, in morning I got success.

Comment: Hi, It's not working android os 5 and above.But its working fine android os 4.3. Do you know why it's not working os 5 and above? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

What you do in body is perfectly correct.

But Gmail reads the extra `android.intent.extra.TEXT`as a string.

You are in fact making a feature request / reporting a bug.

Comment: Edit: You are reporting a bug ; this used to work before 6.11.6.

Comment: I don't know this is a bug from Gmail or some other thing. Because same code whatever I am using right now was working previously before 20 days ago. now Gmail(Mobile app and Browser) what they had changed I don't know. The shared link in <a href tag is not working as a clickable link.

Comment: I agree, same issue here

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:autoLink="web|email"
```

Please add this code in textview xml. It will directly goes gmail link

Comment: @Venky actually I am not using a string at textview. I want to share in default intent; google map link with dynamic latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do using email Intent.  Send email without intent Make email client for sending email. That will support HTML tag.

plz refer

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

Answer (score 0):

After you put your `String` to extra, it lose it attributes as `Spanned`. If you would send it as html, it can be resolved by some applications and shown as you want. Generally, you just put a plain text into the `Bundle` of your `Intent`, and each application interprets it as it wish, so there is no solution to send it as html and force applications to show it as html.

On the other hand, if you know which applications you're going to use via share, you can read its documentation and check if it allows to send hyperlinks via ACTION_SEND intent.

You can tell a receiver that a type of your text by `intent.setType("text/html")`, maybe some applications behavior depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I achieved this issue solution. Thanks, @Faraz.

This is my answer code, as I created tag string in string.xml

```
   <string name="link_to_google_map"><![CDATA[<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=10&q=%1$s+%2$s">LINK TO GOOGLE MAP</a>]]></string>
```

And my code is like this, which works perfectly for sharing using  tag in android:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/html");
    String shareText = "Thank you for using the ReadyAndroid App" + "<br />" +  "Name : " + "ReadyAndroid";
    shareText += "<br />" + "Address : " + "https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/ <br />Mandawa, Jhunjhunu, Rajasthan 333704";
    String mapLocation = String.format(getString(R.string.link_to_google_map), 28.0500, 75.1487);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shareText+mapLocation));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```